# Calendar API representation

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm currently working on an application based on django and django-restframework. The API will deliver json-encoded event/task objects based on the requested time range (weekly). If I consider the backend as a blackbox I come down to an URL/API scheme like the following:

```
calendar/week/<year>/<week_no>/  --> Get all events on isoweek <week_no> in <year>
calendar/week/<year>/            --> Get current isoweek in <year>
calendar/week/                   --> Get current week

calendar/day/<year>/<day_no>/   --> Get all events on isoday <day_no> in <year>
calendar/day/<year>/            --> Get current isoday in <year>
calendar/day/                   --> Get current day
```

As far as I can see this will give me a nice API structure.

This leads me to my problem:
I can't decide which approach to implement this API structure is the "cleanest" with django restframework.

For now I see following possibilities:

- One DefaultRouter for each, day and week
- Implementing an custom router with default url mapping
- Making use of drf-nested-routers module

There is a lack of experience in this issue so I would like to get some opinions on this.

Thanks in advance and best regards

Nerade

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to view all of these "filtering" options as query parameters, and to focus on supporting the filtering itself. If you use this approach your URL would be `/calendar/events/`. The corresponding filtering would be

```
/events/?week=41
/events/?start=DDMMYY&end=DDMMYY
/events/?day=53
```

This would return a list of events every time. If you visited `/events/43/` it would give you the event detail with ID=43

Perhaps of use as background is the [JSON API spec](http://jsonapi.org/) which describes some best practices for organizing an API which helps if you are using a JS framework on the front-end

Comment: Thank you for showing me the approach via filters. I must admit that this idea did not cross my mind so far. Nevertheless I am not quite happy with the format of the url. I personally dislike url parameters if I can avoid them. But since there are no other suggestions on this one I can go this way as a fallback.